# Who exactly is "her" here?

Tags: harry-potter

This dialogues are from *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011):

> Dumbledore: The prophecy did not refer to a woman. It spoke of a boy
> born at the end of July.
>
> Snape: Yes, but he thinks it's **her** son. He intends to hunt them down
> now, to kill them.

Who exactly is "her" here?

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to pay attention when you watch the movies. Most of your questions seem very trivial and the answers are downright obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Her" identity is confirmed in the very next scene.

> **SNAPE:** *You said you would keep her safe!*
>
> **DUMBLEDORE:** *Lily and James* [Potter] *put their faith in the wrong person. Rather like you, Severus.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part II - Screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/scripts/harry-potter-and-the-deathly-hollows-part-2-2011.pdf)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

Lily.

(Do I need to explain this?)

Comment: Well no, but I will anyway. Voldemort thinks the prophecy refers to Harry. Harry is whose son? Lily's. So "her" refers to Lily.